# Powershell script not read value variable

Tags: powershell-3.0

Good afternoon,

I have a code in powershell script, that show if you configure a share folder.

```
DO
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = 'Activar Versionador Automático'
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,180)
    $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

    $okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(380,100)
    $okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $okButton.Text = 'Siguiente'
    $okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $form.AcceptButton = $okButton
    $form.Controls.Add($okButton)

    $actverautLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $actverautLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,10)
    $actverautLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(430,20)
    $actverautLabel.Text = '¿Desea activar el versionador automático?'
    $actverautLabel.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::TopCenter
    $form.Controls.Add($actverautLabel)

    $actverautBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    $actverautBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,40)
    $actverautBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(430,20)
    $actverautBox.Height = 50

    [void] $actverautBox.Items.Add('Si')
    [void] $actverautBox.Items.Add('No')

    $form.Controls.Add($actverautBox)

    $form.Topmost = $true

    $result = $form.ShowDialog()

} while ($actverautBox.Text.Length -eq 0)

## COMPROBAMOS SI ACTIVAMOS EL VERSIONADOR AUTOMATICO ##
    if ($actverautBox.Text -eq 'Si')
    {
        ### Obtenemos la ruta de instalacion del programa ###
        $x = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path Registry::'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Dietetica.exe' -Name Path
        #$x

        $rutaversionador = $x + "\Versionador\"
        #$rutaversionador --> SHOW C:\programa\Versionador\
        #$rutaversionador

        ## COMPARTO LA CARPETA VERSIONADOR COMO VersionadorDT
        New-SmbShare -Name VersionadorDT -Path $rutaversionador -ContinuouslyAvailable $True
    }
```

The problem is when i execute this command "New-SmbShare -Name VersionadorDT -Path $rutaversionador -ContinuouslyAvailable $True", the variable "$rutaversionador" not show me your value, "C:\programa\Versionador", ¿Whats the problem?

Thanks